# Fix a new Dual-Boot Install - broken Windows Partition and no Windows boot option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

Trying to repurpose an old (2005) HP laptop currently running Windows XP.
I had fairly good success putting 32-bit v18.04 Lubuntu on and it created a dual-boot successfully. However, found that Google Chrome (primary app for new use) no longer supports 32-bit and although the laptop is running 32-bit Windows, I do believe it's a 64-bit machine.
I did a Lubuntu 19.10 USB Boot and it was working good, so installed to HDD. It asked if I wanted to keep the Windows partition, but did not ask about dual-boot.
I let it shrink the 100GB drive down so it had about 28GB for Linux and 2GB swap file. Left Windows partition flagged boot. New Linux partition marked root and flagged boot. All appeared to go well.

Linux running ok. It does not offer a Windows boot. GParted also shows the Windows partition with a partitioning error. I tried to Shrink Windows partition a bit to see if that would fix the partition issue, but GParted wouldn't let me and KDE Partition Manager failed during the check before shrinking. Also, Linux file manager won't let me access files in that broken partition. I also looked briefly at it with Grub Customizer.

I could try, but haven't yet, Booting GParted from CD and seeing if it can fix the issue.

**Any ideas how to fix the partition and possibly fix the dual-boot?**

It's not a huge issue as machine was very old, all significant data is off it, and Linux is working (still have WiFi issue).

P.S. I'm a Windows person and VERY RUSTY on Linux. Dabbled a bit back in 2001. Technically minded, but lost on Linux commands.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, Whilst x86_64 started ~2000, x86 or 32-bit only machines were  manufactured/sold up to 2010 so we cannot go by date alone (32-bit windows is cheaper so used on consumer devices). Is your box x86 or amd64 (x86_64)?  Booting Lubuntu 19.10 would imply it's amd64. Windows is usually recognized, however it'll be ignored if hibernated or uncleanly shutdown, but if you have partition errors - I usually opt for wiping the partition, re-creating it & restoring data from backups (the fastest by far), even restoring the system back to all windows (from backups) and starting again.

Comment: It is usually advised to use windows partition tools to work on windows.  I imagine it would be very hard to do that for an XP machine now unless already installed before.  These days quite a few people never touch commands unless they want to.  XP probably should forgotten about(unless needed) and just turn the machine all linux.

Comment: Model HP Pavilion (EH735UA#ABA)
CPU AMD Turion(tm) 64 Mobile Technology ML-34
Version x86 Family 15 Model 36 Stepping 2
Data Width 32bits
Windows Driver Package - Advanced Micro Devices (AmdK8) Processor (05/27/2006 1.3.2.0) 05/27/2006 1.3.2.0
Broadcom 802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter 4.170.77.3
Operating System Microsoft Windows XP Professional
Patch Level Service Pack 3

Some of the terminology they use for 32/64-bit gets confusing, but I'm pretty sure it's a 64-bit PC running 32-bit Win XP.

Comment: "These days quite a few people never touch commands unless they want to."
All GUI with Windows, but Linux is often very command oriented.

It's not a big deal. It's a very old machine.
Would have been nice to be able to read that Windows partition earlier tonight when I was after WiFi drivers, but I found some on another PC.

Right now, I'm still stumped on getting WiFi going on this Linux install.
And it's bogging down quite a bit after I turned on sync in Chrome and open a couple of tabs. The machine may not have enough power and time to get rid of it.

Comment: Linux can be used completely by GUI, but command line is nice also.  Should have enough to run lubuntu decently, unless a hardware problem.  Use a P4 with 1.2GBs ram, not fast but decent enough.  Would google ubuntu with your wireless card.